# Listing *.json files recursively using php

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using php to list all files in a folder recursively:

```
<?php

$it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(".");
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file)
{
    echo $file . "<br/> \n";
}
```

But I would like this script to only list *.json files instead of all the files. How can I achieve this?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: [`fnmatch`](http://php.net/fnmatch), [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) or [`RegexIterator`](http://php.net/RegexIterator) if you wanna go with the theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `->getExtension()` method to check out inside the foreach:

```
$it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(".");
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file) {
    if($file->getExtension() == 'json') { // add a condition here
        echo $file . "<br/> \n";
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because variety:

```
$rdi = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('.');
$rii = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($rdi);
$ri = new RegexIterator($rii, '/^.+\.zzz$/i', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);

foreach ($ri as $file) { ... }
```

$ri will contain a single index array for each .zzz file.

- Modified from the example in the documentation comments: http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php